# Atomic structure and corresponding superpartner behavior

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry

If all quantum particles have a [superpartner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpartner), what happens, if this has been able to be speculated based on theory, to the superpartners when the corresponding partners start forming atoms?

- Is there an S-hydrogen, S-helium, etc.?
- Or are superpartners free particles that cannot form structure?
- Are there spatial interactions; folds/intersections in supersymmetric space that form S-matter?

(edit-clarification)

Alright, maybe the idea that when matter forms, s-matter forms is fundamentally incorrect. Perhaps I put that out there first, even though I figured it to be false, to be falsified first.

However, that aside, these particles do exist (given assumption) and there must be some kind of interaction, lack of interaction, as in, these particles must be doing something. They can't just provide mass for these equations to work...even though that's why they were theorized in the first place, is that correct?
There must be physical ramifications of these particles existing. Have we had any insights into the behavior of these particles?

Do they always exist, do they decay, what is their state in their hidden dimension of space?

Does supersymmetry breaking have behavioral ramifications other than just having unequal mass?
Can we at all determine the composition of this hidden spatial dimension?

Comment: This question sounds familiar--- wasn't there another question on what happens if you super-rotate some chalk? The SUSY is permanently infinitesimal because the generators are Grassman, so a super-hydrogen atom is mostly a H-atom with a little bit of selectron-proton and squark-proton-electron and gluino-proton-electron combinations that are never pure superpartner objects. I can't find the duplicate though.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly the correspondence happens at the level of *fundamental* particles. Quarks imply squarks, leptons imply sleptons and so on. Further, the partners of fermions are bosons and vice versa, so their interaction don't mirror their partners and you should not be thinking about s-nuclons or s-Hydrogen.

Further, it's not that *this* electron has a particular selectron matched with it. It is that the category "electrons" is matched with corresponding category "selectons". So what happens when the electrons combine has no bearing on the fate of the sleptons. They have to make their own way.

Comment: Make their  own way?

Comment: That sounds suspiciously vague

Comment: I understand  this is theory, and probably even getting beyond what we have explored or derived. But if this exists, what is it's nature?